# External Credential Flow (Existing_link)

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, external-services

Struggeling to Authenticate to Microsoft AD With Open ID Connect using Named Credentials/External Credentials.

First of all: This approach works on all Salesforce Instances, now I have this issue on a single Customer-Sandbox.

### My Auth Provider:

[image]

Following things were done:

- Added Client Id / Secret from Connected App within Microsoft AD
- Added Callback URL to Connected App within Microsoft AD

## My External Credentials

[image]

The User has Access through Permissionset for following two things:

1. All Permisions for "User External Credential" Object
2. Permission for the Principal in External Credential (External Credential Principal Access)

### Execution

After this, the User is able to start the authentication flow through his User Settings:

[image]

This Flow successfully authenticated the User at Microsoft AD and finally redirects user to Callback URL. At this point i allways get following:

[image]

In the URL there is following ErrorCode:

> AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=Existing_link&startURL=XXXX

Sadly this ErrorCode is not mentioned by Salesforce: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flow_errors.htm&language=en_US&type=5

This approach works perfectly on several Salesforce instances, only not on this specific one.
What I've compared with working Salesforce Instances:

- Sessions Settings
- IP Restrictions

Does anybody experienced same?
How to get the root cause for "Existing_Link"? I got somewhere at StackExchange, that this ErrorCode is raised if no Access to "User External Credential" is granted. But this Permission is granted.

Any suggestion?

Comment: _How to get the root cause for "Existing_Link_ : learn and understand the OpenID Connect protocol, then reproduce the calls using command-line tools. You _might_ be able to explain the issue then. Or you can try your luck by opening a support case.

Comment: @identigral don't think so, sorry for that. Since MS redirects me, withouth any Exception and Salesforce just swallows the exception, I don't see any chance - even with command line - that salesforce will provide a different information.. It says "I dont like it, but i do not say why".

Comment: The error is produced by SF based on what MS sends. Yes, it's possible that this is SF-specific and independent of MS but that is unlikely. Therefore doing this on command-line is going to help. Even if you can't reproduce it on command-line, merely by trying you'd gain a lot more understanding of what's going on.